# Tags needing synonymification/consolidation

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

--I think these are uncontroversial duplicates.  I think we should make them synonyms to avoid repeat cleanup.  I think a mod should do it to avoid bumping threads (or give me the ability to do it).

**Merged**

- avocado/avocados
- castiron/cast-iron
- cocktail/cocktails
- comparison/comparisons
- egg-white/egg-whites
- measurement/measurements
- mushroom/mushrooms
- recipe/recipes
- technique/techniques
- tomato/tomatoes
- yogurt/yoghurt

**Suggested**

- alternative/substitute/replacement
- baked/baking
- bake-time/cooking-time
- bbq/barbeque
- burger/burgers/hamburger
- freezer/freezing/freezer-cooking
- sharpeners/sharpening
- smoke/smoking
- tradition/traditional
- waste/disposal
- taste/flavor
- method/technique
- shopping/buying
- beverage/beverages
- myth/cooking-myth

**Remaining**

- market/shopping/buying
- budget-cooking/cost
- corrections/recipe-problems
- crudo/sushi
- historical/history/traditional/authentic
- home-cooking/homemade? ( home-cooking has one tag about utensils)
- bacteria/mother-culture/starter
- conversion/measurement
- selection/food-selection/ingredients-selection

---

All suggested synonyms can be viewed here:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested

Comment: I suggest any objections should be put in the answers and people should vote for them if they agree with the objection.  any without objection could be done after a while

Comment: For those not aware there are tools in place for the community to propose and vote on tag synonyms: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/

Answer (score 1):

I have suggested the synonyms noted above. Some were not eligible for suggestion due to the tag not being present. The others I omitted because I do not feel they should be synonyms.

Comment: great, organizing the list helps

Comment: the ineligible ones were just the wrong plural (beverage/beverages). i updated it

Answer (score 1):

After searching through the meta site for a bit, I'm a little confused as to where a 'low point' user like me can suggest tags that are synonymous. Here seems like the best place (please point me to a better place, if one exists).

While I was tagging a recent post, I noticed `[Onion]` and `[Onions]` are both tags, and `[Onions]` has significantly fewer uses.

Also, because I'm curious by nature, I poked in the tags section and found:

- `[sausage]`/`[sausages]`
- `[apple]`/`[apples]`

Comment: Thanks ... I'll go fix them ... we had decided to go with the convention of using [plurals or collectives for nouns and with the -ing form for verbs](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/511/retagging-recap).  (is that infinitive?  I think I've blocked out all of the verb-tense stuff from grammer class)

Comment: The technical term is a gerund. (Now I feel like I should be pointing to the grammar board.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will definitely do the pluralized ones. I'll cross them out as I go. The rest I'll leave alone for a vote by the community.

Comment: I don't know if you guys are aware of this, but tag voting is built-in.

Comment: It looks like tag voting became available *very* recently, or at least the synonym function. I'm still looking to see how it works.  We might need a separate post announcing the feature.

Comment: Yes, I meant leave it to the community there.

Comment: Merge completed for plurals that were suggested.

Comment: What do you mean, Mike?

Comment: I meant that I merged the obvious synonyms, and I left the rest for the community to vote on in the tag synonym admin.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Got it.

Comment: Once the community votes to approve a merge, does it happen automatically? I've read the blog post about voting on tags, and I can't tell quite how it will work.

Comment: @JuatRightMenus, 4 votes (or one from a mod) locks in a synonym, -2 deletes it. At that point, after the synonym is created, mods can then perform a merge to auto retag questions with the old tag to the new tag. The synonym creation is automatic, but merging looks like it's mod only at the moment.

Comment: Right now it shows that yoghurt/yogurt and replacement/substitutions need a merge. That means they've already been approved and one of us mods just needs to do the merge, right?

Comment: @JustRightMenus, yes. However, I didn't do the merge because I'm not sure we really want to go through with it. In fact, I'm more tempted to delete that synonym (and the rest I approved and merged) and give it more time till we have more data.

Comment: @Mike Sherov is it impossible to reverse the hierarchy (parent-child) *after* a synonym is created?

Comment: Ocassi, no, but it's very tedious. You have to delete the synonym, manually retag the more than half the questions, suggest the reverse retag, accept it and then merge. That's why it's taking me a while to reverse them.

Comment: @Mike Sherov I'd say that's basically impossible.  Why won't SO/SE allow mods to override the master/majority feature to allow for retags in situations where the synonym was accepted through a vote?